# Making a Menu using unordered list?

Tags: css, html-lists

It can be a very basic question but i am unable to find any help on google after hours of searching so i posted it.

I want to get a menu like this using unordered list.

[image]

In my case all the extra list item goes out of the div, so i floated all li elements to the left but there is new problem. I want the li to go on side when there is no more space at bottom, but they are always on side even if there is space at bottom. For eg. in below image i want "WOMEN" to be below the "MEN" list not on the side ('Don't take it the wrong way if you know what i mean ;) )

[image]

So can anyone help me

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="list">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="">
                          <a href="#" class="heading">ELECTRONICS</a>
                          <ul><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Mobiles</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Tablets</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Laptops</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Network Components</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Computer Peripherals</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Mobile Accessories</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Television</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Home Appliences</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Kitchen Appliences</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Kitchen Appliences</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Gaming</a></li><li>
                          <a href="#" class="item">Cameras</a></li></ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="heading">MEN</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Clothing</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Footware</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Watches</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Accessories</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Spectacle Frames</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Bag, Belts & Wallets</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Sunglasses</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Fragrances</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="item">Grooming & Wellness</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#" class="heading">WOMEN</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>hello></li>
                      <li>hello></li>
                      <li>hello></li>
                      <li>hello></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
     .wrapper {
           display:

 none;
       height: 400px;
       width: 1266px;
    }
   .wrapper > di ul {
       float: lft;  
 }
.wrapper div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding-top: 30px;  
}

.list a.heading {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.list a.item {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.list > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Could you post what you did so far ? I understand the picture is what you want. But we can't help you if we don't now what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTMl, you see that the lists that are already there exist from an unordered list inside of one unordered list item. Your `hello` nodes however, were not in an unordered list but in regular list items.

Add `<ul>` tags to your list items to make it work, have a look at my snippet to see how.

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    width: 1266px;
}
.wrapper > div ul {
    float: left;
}
.wrapper div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.list a.heading {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.list a.item {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.list > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#" class="heading">ELECTRONICS</a>
                <ul><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Mobiles</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Tablets</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Laptops</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Network Components</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Computer Peripherals</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Mobile Accessories</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Television</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Home Appliences</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Kitchen Appliences</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Kitchen Appliences</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Gaming</a></li><li>
                    <a href="#" class="item">Cameras</a></li></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="heading">MEN</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Clothing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Footware</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Watches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Spectacle Frames</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Bag, Belts & Wallets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Sunglasses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Fragrances</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="item">Grooming & Wellness</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="heading">WOMEN</a>
            </li>
            <ul> <!-- <<<<<<<<<<< notice these <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< -->
                <li>hello></li>
                <li>hello></li>
                <li>hello></li>
                <li>hello></li>
            </ul> <!-- <<<<<<<<<< notice these <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: those li are already in an ul and i will use them to place ul inside them. I want those li to come in a new column when there is no space in bottom

Comment: @Dimensionless If you don't mind putting your elements in `div` tags instead of lists, check out css `flex-box` techniques. That does the trick.

Comment: yeah i know that technique but i kind of wanted to use ul. That will the plan if i dont find a way to make it work